# Rails: how to save few elements from string

Tags: forms, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have rails form_tag helper to save data provided by do..each loop. This is my form:

```
          <%= form_tag (customers_path) do |f| %>
                 < @contacts.each do |c|%>
                     <%= check_box_tag "accept[]", c %><%= c[:email] %>
                 <% end %>  
                <%= submit_tag ("Save") %>
          <%end%>
```

This form saves the contacts whose checkbox is checked. Here is what, c has:

```
 "accept"=>["{:id=>\"2f310f1d9b8f\",
 :first_name=>\"San\",
   :last_name=>\"Jori\",
    :name=>\"Jori,San\",
  :email=>\"abc@qwe.com\",
    :gender=>nil,
  :birthday=>nil,
  :profile_picture=>nil,
    :relation=>nil}"],
    "commit"=>"Save"
```

I want to save only :name and :email from above hash.
This is my create action of controller:

```
    if params[:accept].present?
    params[:accept].each do |customer|
        @customer = current_user.customers.new(:name => customer[:name], :email => customer[:email])
    @customer.save
    end 
  redirect_to customers_path
    end
```

But it is giving error of :

```
   no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
```

Can anyone tell me how to make it work?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
@customer = current_user.customers.new(:name => customer[:name], :email => customer[:email])
```

Try

```
@customer = current_user.customers.build(:name => customer[:name], :email => customer[:email])
```

Comment: the solution u have given displays o/p as 'name' and 'email' not value in it. It should display Jori,San, abc@qwe.com.

Comment: I guess something wrong happens at a different layer then; what happens when you add "p customer" inside the each block?

Comment: it gives this: {:id=>"112f310f1d9b8f", :first_name=>"San", :last_name=>"Jori", :name=>"Jori, San", :email=>"abc@qwe.com", :gender=>nil, :birthday=>nil, :profile_picture=>nil, :relation=>